# Why im getting this error invalid Payload?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";

async function notifyUser(message ,title, photoURL,token , uid , notificationsOn ) {

  const messages = [];

  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: message,
    },
    data: {
      uid,
    },
    android: {
      notification: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "mutable-content": 1,
        },
      },
      fcm_options: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
  };

  try {
 if (token) {
     

   
  messages.push({ token: token, ...payload });
  console.log("yes");
}
    

    if (messages.length && notificationsOn==true) {
      await admin.messaging().sendAll(messages);
      console.log("Token for user, send notification.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");

    functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's an object:", error);
   

    console.log(photoURL);
  console.log(notificationsOn);
      console.log(token);
      console.log(message);
      console.log(uid);
      console.log(title)
    console.log("No token for user, can not send notification.");
   
    return {error:error.code};
  }

  return;
};

export {notifyUser} ;
```

The error I get

[image]

The line 169 is this line

```
 await admin.messaging().sendAll(messages);
```

It's always logging "No token for user cannot send notification". And I don't have any idea why. I checked like 30 times. The logs are not empty and give the correct output. The token is not empty.

It's not working on both android and iOS. But when sending notification via firebase to android or iOS it works. And notification retrieved .

Hope really anyone has and idea. I also tried to send notification from firebase via token. This also works . And as I said I checked every output it should work but does not.

If you think I did something wrong in configuration in my project please tell me what I you think it can be .

Comment: I recommend logging the messages with `console.log(JSON.stringify(messages)) ` right before you call `admin.messaging().sendAll(messages)`.

Comment: Yes I fixed it with adding this into payload token:token.  Now its sending messages but the problem is its sending the same message 100 times think its because of my frontend code . Maybe you can check out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comes out that adding this statement

token:token like this

```
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: title,
      body: message,
    },
    token: token,
    data: {
      uid,
    },
    android: {
      notification: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "mutable-content": 1,
        },
      },
      fcm_options: {
        image: photoURL,
      },
    },
  };
```

into payload but outside of all other statements fixed the issue.